# How to post gzipped data to CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, gzip

As of version 1.6.0, CouchDB can now accept gzipped JSON request bodies. I am posting a bunch of JSON files via the browser, and being able to compress them would save a lot of bandwidth. How do I make an ajax post of gzipped json docs to couchdb?

Comment: Here's how to do it with curl:
curl -XPOST -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @file.json.gz --compressed http://foo.couchappy.com/foo

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

1. Compress your JSON files.
2. Send the AJAX request with the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header.

For step one you can use a JS library. A few examples:

- [js-deflate](https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate)
- [gzip-js](https://github.com/beatgammit/gzip-js)
- [pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako)

For step 2, using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) you can do

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
```

or using JQuery, add

```
headers: {"Content-Encoding": "gzip"}
```

to the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) settings.